# Websphere MQ setting up SSPI Kerberos

Tags: ibm-mq, kerberos, sspi

how can i properly setup Kerberos in Websphere MQ? In the documentation, it says can use

```
SCYEXIT('amqrspin(SCY_KERBEROS)')
```

I suppose this attribute is defined when when create the channels? eg

```
define CHANNEL (...) .... SCYEXIT('amqrspin(SCY_KERBEROS)')
```

how about `SCYDATA('remote_principal_name')` ? Does this need to defined after `scyexit` ? What other setups do I need to consider besides these 2 channel attributes?

is there other good tutorial on this subject? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `amqrspin` security exit shipped with MQ supports KERBEROS and NTLM. A channel can be defined to use the security exit as

```
 define channel(ABC) chltype(SVRCONN) SCYEXIT('amqrspin(SCY_KERBEROS)') SCYDATA('domusr')
```

where 'domusr' is in the form DOMAIN\user. The secure channel is established only if the name of the remote principal matches 'domusr'. [Here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q024600_.htm) is some more information on `amqrspin` security exit.